# Strange output when fetching order data

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, shipping-methods, integrate

I am trying to integrate my store (community edition 1.9) with ShipWorks.

I have followed the instructions on both ends and for the most part everything is working as it should. However when I try to download the order data into Shipworks. I get an error that basically says there is something in this file (xml) that should not be there.
After a lot of back and forth with both ShipWorks and my hosting company I have narrowed the problem down to an extraneous character that is showing up in the xml, when viewed with notepad ++ it looks like a very small superscript asterisk.

I have further narrowed the issue and discovered that this character appears when ever the code:
`` $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();` ``

is called. I have tried looking at the Mage.php file to see if I can further deduce the problem but I am not entirely sure what to look for and don't want to start messing with core files.

Can anyone tell me whats happening/how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things I'd try:

1. Look at the shipworks.php (or shipworks3.php, whatever they call their bridge now) to ensure that there's not some extra character at the top of the file before the `<?php`
2. Since you're saying that this character shows up every time the getCollection is called then you probably have an extra character in there too.  You could re-download the exact version of Magento that you're running and overwrite the app/code/core/Mage folder (the goal being to replace all of the files with original Core files).  Backup first!

Comment: Thanks! Overwriting the core files seems to have done the trick!